# Printing first variable (index=0) at the end

Tags: python

I'm trying to attach the first element of comma separated strings at the end. If user inputs 'first, second, third' then it should return ['first', 'second', 'third', 'first']

So I'm really close to completing it but my code returns ['first', 'second', 'third] first

I was thinking of using .append() first and then print the code. Can somebody elaborate on .append()?

```
s = input('Please enter a series of comma-separated strings: ')
l = s.split(",")
print(l,l[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `append()` function allows a user to add a value to the end of a list.
So if your list is `["hi", 1, "hello"]`
and we do a `my_list.append(100)` the new list will be come
`["hi", 1, "hello", 100]`

for your case all you need to do is read the values into the list as you are doing
split it
and then

```
s = input('Please enter a series of comma-separated strings: ')
l = s.split(",")
l.append(l[0])
print(l)
```

Your list will be in the proper format now.

Comment: When I tried .append(), I defined a variable newl= l.append(l[0]). How come I can't print newl?